# C# - From a function, how do I return a boolean Type? (As reference, not value)

Tags: c#, function, boolean, return-type

Is it possible to return a Boolean Type?

Something like...

```
public static bool someBool = false;

public TypeOf<Bool> findBool(string id)
{
   if (id == "item1")
       return someBool;
}
```

So, just to be extra clear, I don't want it to return "false".  I want it to actually return a reference to "someBool".   So then in another method (where it's returned) I can do something like this...

```
public void someMethod()
{
    bool boolObj = findBool("item1");
    boolObj = true;
}
```

I know this probably doesn't make much sense, but I want to do it this way for a reason.

Thanks,
iBenji

Comment: FYI: This functionality is coming with C# 7.

Comment: can you wrap it in a class and use it instead of a `bool` directly?

Comment: Actually, that's a really good idea!  I never thought of wrapping it in a class first.  That would work!